# Limitations of curl and wget

Tags: curl, wget

I am wondering why certain URLs load without a hassle in a browser tab but timeout with tools like `wget` and `curl`.
Here is an example URL:
https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines

I have tried creating download scripts for this webpage using `curl` and `wget` but without success (i.e. they all hang up).

```
wget --adjust-extension -t 2 -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines" -O gme.html

wget --adjust-extension -t 2 -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36' "www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines" -O gme.html

curl -o 01.html https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines

curl -o 01.html www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/gme/news-headlines
```

Answer (score 1):

When the page loads, you first see a blank box, and then the news and price show up. This is because the javascript on the page is doing an API call for the information.  Curl and wget don't run any javascript, just download the contents of the page, that's why you won't see anything. You have to find the actual api call, and download that.